# WordPress not showing more than 10 posts

Tags: wordpress

I am showing posts by shortcode into posts/pages of WordPress, and want to show an infinite list of posts, but it is showing only 10 posts.

Here is my code; please guide me what is wrong with my query.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'cat' => '2', 'meta_key' => 'issue_of_article', 'meta_value' => $issue, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'artcle_category', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     $loop->the_post();
     <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Just add this in your argument

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

then you are done.

One more thing: you can change the default setting from admin to something other than 10. Go to the WordPress admin - Settings - Reading. There is an option like "Blog pages show at most". Type there the number of posts you want as the default.

Comment: This is already added in arguments array, i can not change Reading settings because it will affect on all system, while i want to change for my this code only. Thanks

Comment: I checked by removing "meta_key" and "meta_value" then "posts_per_page" works, if i include these parameters "posts_per_page" does not work, while i have checked from admin panel posts are more than 10.

Comment: One thing have to remind is that it should come before `meta_query` if you are searching a post by meta values.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings menu in the admin page

Settings -> Reading
Change the value for **Blog pages show at most**.

It will work.

Comment: i can not change Reading settings because it will affect on all system, while i want to change for my this code only. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

or

```
'posts_per_page' => 1000
```

Both of these should work.

Comment: One thing have to remind is that it should come before `meta_query` if you are searching a post by meta values.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question maybe but why do you call $loop->the_post(); twice ? Isn't it the source of the problem ? (each loop calls 2 posts at a time)

Answer (score 0):

You can decide how many posts to show in the loop:

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php  

    $loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'resource',
            'order_by'       => 'post_id',
            'order'          => 'ASC',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 100
        )                    
    );

?>

<?php while ($loop -> have_posts()): $loop -> the_post(); ?>

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. At first - post WP questions at [**Wordpress.Stackexchange.com**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)
2. The good way is to add in **`functions.php`**:

   add_action('pre_get_posts','myfunc');
   function myfunc($query){
   if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive){
   $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1000);
   }
   return $query;
   }